# Is there a good pre-existing class for dealing with URLs in PHP?

Tags: php, url

Is there a widely accepted class for dealing with URLs in PHP?

Things like: getting/changing parts of an existing URL (e.g. path, scheme, etc), resolving relative paths from a base URL.  Kind of like a two-way [parse_url()](http://php.net/parse_url), encapsulated with a bunch of handy functions.

Does something like this exist?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You've got the [Net_URL2](http://pear.php.net/package/Net_URL2/docs) package over at PEAR, which appears to have replaced the [original Net_URL](http://pear.php.net/package/Net_URL/docs).  I have no first hand experience with it, but I'll almost always take a PEAR package over "random library found on website".

Answer (score 4):

This **[URL.php class](http://www.phpclasses.org/browse/file/3008.html)** may be a good start (not sure it is 'widely' accepted though).

> URL class intended for http and https schemes
>
> This class allows you store absolute or relative URLs and access it's various parts (scheme, host, port, part, query, fragment).
>
> It will also accept and attempt to resolve a relative URL against an absolute URL already stored.
>
> Note: this URL class is based on the HTTP scheme.
>
> Example:

```
$url =& new URL('http://www.domain.com/path/file.php?query=blah');
echo $url->get_scheme(),"\n";    // http
echo $url->get_host(),"\n";      // www.domain.com
echo $url->get_path(),"\n";      // /path/file.php
echo $url->get_query(),"\n";     // query=blah
// Setting a relative URL against our existing URL
$url->set_relative('../great.php');
echo $url->as_string(); // http://www.domain.com/great.php
```

Answer (score -1):

[`Zend_Uri`](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.uri.html) is a good candidate.